# Are there in jQuery some methods for handling period of time data type?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I'm new in jQuery and all of my search requests bring me to methods for handling Date/Time data types. But I need to handle some period of time, given in number of minutes. I want to convert, for example, `1708` minutes to `"1 day and 4 hours"` expression, ignoring minutes. There is `TimeSpan` data type in C#, for example, and I can do following:

```
public string ConvertMinutes()
        {
            //Number of minutes I have and want to convert
            int n = 1708;
            TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, n, 0);

            string dayshelper = t.Days == 1 ? "day" : "days";
            string hoursHelper = t.Hours == 1 ? "hour" : "hours";

            //The result I want to get
            //For example "4 days and 2 hours"
            string result = string.Empty;
            result += t.Days == 0 ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0} {1}", t.Days, dayshelper);
            result += t.Hours == 0 ? "." : string.Format(" and {0} {1}.", t.Hours, hoursHelper);
            return result;
        }
```

Is there something similar in jQuery? Or do I have to get number of days and hours from number of minutes by myself?

Comment: time is one of easiest data structures to get what you're looking for. Very simple math conversions that would be trivial to implement yourself.... There isn't something stock in jQuery nor javascript like what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The point is I've already have such function, and I just wanted to know is there in jQuery something ready, because I didn't want to "reinvent he wheel" as I often like to do )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like that built into jQuery. Javascript has some basic functions built in for handling dates like `new Date()` which will get you "now", or `new Date().getTime()` which will get you the epoch. But there is nothing really good at dates.

http://www.datejs.com/

I like this library quite a bit. It works well and does everything. Enjoy!

Otherwise you can always write the function by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your own function in javascript to convert minutes to string. All you need to do is to do modulus division to get whole part and reminder. Keep dividing by 60 or 24 depending what dimension you are in until you get 0 in the whole part.

So for 1000 seconds I would do

1000 / 60 = 16 minutes
1000 % 60 = 40 seconds reminder